# Adding new json configuration after the host was built

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to add a second configuration source after the host was built and cant get the correct IConfiguration instance injected into dependent services.

I keep an instance of IConfigurationBuilder and after the host is built and running, I am calling this api to add json settings file

```
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(appSettingsFile, false, false);
```

Still any instance of IConfiguration that gets injected into dependent services does not have the json file provider and cant load the configuration from it.
Perhaps its not possible to add any new configuration files after the host was built ?

Comment: The question is unclear. What does `Adding new json configuration after the host was built` mean? You can read as many settings files as you want, provided they actually exist. You can also have the provider track them for changes, and read the latest config settings. If the file *doesn't* exist at all though, it won't be tracked just in case it appears later on. Your code explicitly *disables* reloading on change, so any changes made to the file won't be tracked

Comment: `after the host is built and running` what does that mean? There's no `configurationBuilder` available after you build the host. Configuration is set up in `ConfigureAppConfiguration ` *before* you call `Build()`. What does your actual code look like?

Comment: I create HostBuilder in ConfigureAppConfiguration i capture IConfigurationBuilder and keep it in a shared variable, then call build on HostBuilder and produce a host which then runs with RunAsync, later in code i re-use the IConfigurationBuilder instance and add new configuration from json file, as noted it does not work. In general my goal is to be able to add a new configuration source (json) and be later to use it in any dependent services. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code, don't describe it. "Capturing" is meaningless because that builder won't be used again. It's not needed either. You still haven't explained what you want to do and why you don't configure that file from the start. You're configuring the provider at that point, not hard-coding the actual values. There are a lot of configuration providers that retrieve values just in time, from remote sources or databases.

Comment: Yes I looked into the IConfigurationSource and it looks like I can have the system working the way I want by using it.